# UICollectionView built-in reordering not working correctly for cells of different sizes

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

`UICollectionView` added support for re-ordering cells in iOS 9, but the live interaction doesn't work correctly if all the cells are not of the same size:

Notice in this screen capture how swapping cells #3 and #2, which have the same size, works correctly, while it doesn't for cells #3 and #1:

[image]

Basically it appears the `UICollectionView` is not recomputing the layout of the other cells while moving the selected cell. Does anyone know of a work around?

Another related issue is that when re-ordering of cells of different sizes has completed, you need to manually invalidate the `UICollectionView` layout, otherwise some cells have invalid positions and overlap.

PS: I'm using a long press gesture recognizer and calling these methods as needed:

```
- (BOOL)beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0); // returns NO if reordering was prevented from beginning - otherwise YES
- (void)updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition:(CGPoint)targetPosition NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
- (void)endInteractiveMovement NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
- (void)cancelInteractiveMovement NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who have this problem, the reason is that `UICollectionView` doesn't re-arrange the *layout attributes* for the items while dragging is happening.

What I mean is that if item #2 is 50x50 and item #3 is 100x100, while live dragging items and swapping them around, `UICollectionView` doesn't automatically swap their sizes as well. Whatever is at position 2 is always assumed to be 50x50 and whatever is at position 3 is always assumed to be 100x100.

The solution is to ensure that, when an item is moved around, the `UICollectionView` data source is *continuously* updated to reflect the new position. The best way to do that seems to be in the `UICollectionView` delegate method:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
       targetIndexPathForMoveFromItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)originalIndexPath
       toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedIndexPath
```